# Screen caption custom colors

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, colors, ansi-term

I am having trouble customizing the color of my caption in screen. I can use the 8 standard colors supported (as well as their brighter versions), but I am unable to define a custom color.

The docs for screen state: "[Colors are coded either as a hexadecimal number or two letters](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/screen/screen_138.html)". It does not seem to define anywhere what format to write the hex number in. I have tried several random ways but so far none seem to work.

Does anyone know how to use a custom color in screen?

Comment: `screen` doesn't get the last word on this, the capabilities of the terminal do.  Most only have 16 colors -- two versions of the basic eight -- and custom colors won't work.

Comment: @goldilocks I know my terminal supports more colors than this - VI displays some of my text in a nice muted green that I want to use.

Comment: Konsole, gnome-terminal, and some others are capable of 256 colors, but it's still a pre-configured fixed palette.  Try `echo -e "\\033[32mhey\\033[1mhey\\033[0m"` and see if one of those is the green you are looking for.

Comment: @goldilocks Hmm, those seem to be showing similar colors. Out of curiosity, do you know how I would specify a color code like that for caption?

Comment: Those are the two greens; the first is the basic green and the second bright aka. bold green.  The `[NNm` numbers are ANSI codes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors If you scroll up and look at the "SGR parameters" chart above that you'll notice 30-37 is foreground and 40-47 background.  You could try translating those to hex and see if they work; `[1m` adds the bold and `[0m` resets.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for `caption`:

```
caption always "%{= 2f} CAP %3n %t"
```

I added the string `CAP` just to prove that the caption is being used.  According to the manual, the default for this is `"%3n %t"`.

You apply *attributes* and *colors* within the `"%{ }"` markers.  Attributes come first, and it is simplest to set a color if you just force a dummy attribute (as I do here with "=" followed by a blank.

The `2f` is a hexadecimal color value (a green background: just a `2` would give green text).  The intent of the hexadecimal number is to give values 0-15 for each of the background and foreground colors.

By the way, there is no direct relationship between colors used in `caption`, etc., versus the colors that an application may use when running inside `screen`: the latter can be more than 16 colors, while attributes cannot.  To see this, you would have to read the source code because the documentation is lacking in detail, e.g,.

- [process.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/process.c) (attributes),
- [termcap.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/termcap.c) (looking at what the terminal can do) and
- [display.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/display.c) (what's actually shown).